# Белый экран при переходе между активити

Tags: java, android

Мне нужно чтоб после успешной регистрации пользователя его сразу кидало на гланвый экран (MainActivity). Но почему то вместо нормальной загрузки я получаю только белый экран, MainActivity не загружается.

AuthAndReg.java

```
    public class AuthAndReg extends AppCompatActivity {
    
        private EditText EdTextPassword, edUserEmail;
        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth_and_reg);

            init();
            final EditText et_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EdTextPassword);
            final ImageButton bt_change_mode = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.bt_change_mode);
            final TextView ChangeModText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ChangeModText);
            bt_change_mode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

       @Override
      public void onClick(View view) {
     if (EdTextPassword.getInputType () == 128
        EdTextPassword.setInputType (129); 
        ChangeModText.setText ("Показывать пароль");
}
else {
     EdTextPassword.setInputType (128); 
       ChangeModText.setText ("Скрыть пароль");
    
}
            EdTextPassword.setSelection (EdTextPassword.getText (). length ());}});
    
    
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            FirebaseUser cUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        }
    
        private void init()
        {
    
            EdTextPassword = findViewById(R.id.EdTextPassword);
            edUserEmail = findViewById(R.id.edUserEmail);
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        }
    
    
        public void onClickAuth(View view){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, AuthUser.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    
    
        public void OnClickHelp(View view)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, RegInfoPage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    
    
    
    
    
    
        public void onClickReg(View view){
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(edUserEmail.getText().toString()) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(EdTextPassword.getText().toString()) )
            {
    
                mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword (edUserEmail.getText().toString(),EdTextPassword.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful())
                        {
    
                            Toast.makeText(AuthAndReg.this, "Добро пожаловать, вы успешно зарегистрировались", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(AuthAndReg.this, MainActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
    
    
    
    
    
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(AuthAndReg.this, "Что-то пошло не так" , 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
    
                    }
                });
    
    
            }
    
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(AuthAndReg.this, "Пожалуйста, заполните все поля" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    
    
    
    
        }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
        public void onClickGoBack(View view){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    }
```

MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
        private TextView   edUserEmail;
    
    
    
            @Override
            public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                //Intent intent = getIntent();
                ImageButton RegButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.RegButton);
    
                RegButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AuthAndReg.class));
                    }
                });
            }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
        public void buttonclick(View view){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, CatalogActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
    
    
        }
    
    
        public void openRegPage(View v){
            Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, AuthAndReg.class);
            startActivity(intent1);
    
    
        }}
```

activity_auth_and_reg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/regButton"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AuthAndReg">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edUserEmail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/enterEmail"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:textColorHint="#757575"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView9"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04000002" />

    <!--    <ImageButton-->
    <!--        android:id="@+id/auth_button"-->
    <!--        android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"-->
    <!--        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"-->
    <!--        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"-->
    <!--        android:onClick="onClickAuth"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"-->
    <!--        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_button_auth" />-->
    <!--    <ImageButton-->
    <!--        android:id="@+id/Reg_Button"-->
    <!--        android:layout_width="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:layout_height="wrap_content"-->
    <!--        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"-->
    <!--        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"-->
    <!--        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"-->
    <!--        android:onClick="onClickReg"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/auth_button"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.511"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/EdTextEmail"-->
    <!--        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_button_reg" />-->


    <!--    <ImageView-->
    <!--        android:id="@+id/imageView"-->
    <!--        android:layout_width="366dp"-->
    <!--        android:layout_height="287dp"-->
    <!--        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/edName"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"-->
    <!--        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"-->
    <!--        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_def_shop" />-->


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/EdTextPassword"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autofillHints=""
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="@string/firstpassword"
        android:inputType="text|textPassword"
        android:minHeight="48dp"
        android:textColorHint="#757575"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/RegButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edUserEmail"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.00999999" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="408dp"
        android:layout_height="338dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_logo1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/AuthButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.01999998"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_defshop" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/AuthButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:onClick="onClickAuth"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/RegButton"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.04000002"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_authbutton" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/RegButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:onClick="onClickReg"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.85"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_regbutton" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/RegText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:text="@string/reg_title"
        android:textColor="#0E0E0E"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.050000012" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/backbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:onClick="onClickGoBack"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/RegText"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.38"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_gobackbutton" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ChangeModText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
        android:text="@string/ShowPasswrod"
        android:textColor="#272727"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/RegButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.41"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/EdTextPassword"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.32999998" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/bt_change_mode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/RegButton"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.72"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/EdTextPassword"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_button_password" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/InfoButton"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="3dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="32dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:onClick="OnClickHelp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/EdTextPassword"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.59000003"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_infobutton" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: В `onClickReg` добавь `finish()`

Comment: Добавил. К сожалению, не помогло.

Comment: может разметку mainActivity покажете? вероятнее всего где-то там может быть проблема, попробуйте под отладкой посмотреть приходите ли вы на другой экран

Comment: Спасибо, оказывается проблема оказалась в вызове OnCreate